# Play/BoneCP message "releaseHelperThreads has been deprecated"

Tags: scala, playframework-2.2, bonecp

Does anyone know if the following message obtained when starting a Play 2.2 app is important or not?

```
WARN  - releaseHelperThreads has been deprecated 
  -- it tends to slow down your application more.
```

I cannot find this setting anywhere, and most references to the message are just log output. I'm assuming it is a bonecp setting, but can't see where play is setting it, if, in fact, it is doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from [this](https://github.com/Timshel/Play20/commit/fa4ca29d26be2bb98aaca476503558bcaf16db63), play is setting releaseHelperThreads to 0 (disabled?), but as the setting is deprecated, any call to the setter produces the warning message. If I understood the code comments correctly, the message will disappear once Play moves to BoneCP 0.8.0 or beyond. Bottom line: nothing to worry about.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are using

```
BoneCPConfig config = new BoneCPConfig();
config.setReleaseHelperThreads(1);
```

Or

```
< property name="releaseHelperThreads" value="1" />
```

`setReleaseHelperThreads` method is deprecated in version 0.8.0.RELEASE, that's why it showing "releaseHelperThreads has been deprecated -- it tends to slow down your application more." warning.

This setReleaseHelperThreads(1) method is used to sets number of helper threads to create that will handle releasing a connection.

Comment: Tks but I was not explicitly setting it. Message is gone now in play 2.3 (bonecp 0.8.0.release).